# How does the recursive call work in this erlang function?

Tags: function, recursion, erlang

```
fun({0, M}) -> {M+1, M-2};
fun({N, M}) ->
 {A, B} = fun({N-1, M+1}),
            {B, A+1}.
```

so I am kinda unsure of what the A and B would be and how the next recursive call would be. let say 2,2

so it would be

```
f(2,2) -> {A,B} = fun({1,3}), {B,A+1}
f(1,3) -> {A,B} = fun({0,4}), {B,A+1}
f(0,4) -> {5,2}
```

but where does A and B go and do they change in each recursive call?

Comment: Each call is a new context -- the exception is when you are deliberately closing over some external state. Consider backing up a bit to a more general explanation of some recursive idioms: [Explanation of lists:foldl function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854586/explanation-of-listsfold-function/26855055#26855055)

Answer (score 2):

As a *very* basic explanation of "where is my variable", consider the countdown function in this example module:

```
-module(example).
-export([countdown/1]).


-spec countdown(non_neg_integer()) -> ok.

countdown(0) ->
    io:format("Blastoff!~n");
countdown(N) when N > 0 ->
    ok = io:format("Counting down in: ~w~n", [N]),
    Next = N - 1,
    countdown(Next).
```

If we hit the *base case*, which is `0`, then we stop. The return value of the function overall is the atom `ok` (because that is the return value of a successful call to [`io:format/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#format-2)).

If the input is greater than `0` then we match on the second clause, which means we assign `N` the sole input argument *for this particular iteration*. The next thing we do is make our output call. Then we assign `Next` to the value `N - 1`. Then we call the same function again (do a loop) using the value of `Next` in body of the the current call as the input argument.

The next iteration *all the variables are totally new because this is a fresh execution context*. The old `N` and `Next` no longer exist. In fact, they don't event exist on a stack anywhere because Erlang uses "[tail call optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?TailCallOptimization)" to maintain recursive tail calls in [constant space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization), the same way most other languages would do an explicit `for` or `while` or `do while` or [insert form].

As Alexy points out, be careful about the token `fun` -- it is a keyword in Erlang, not a legal function name. It is the non-name of an [anonymous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) (also known as a [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501/what-is-a-lambda-function)). In other words, unless you provide a label, the name of every anonymous function is just `fun`.

`fun` is also the keyword that is used to reference a function by label (to use as a value itself) instead of calling it. For example, `countdown(10)` calls the function above with an argument of `10`. *Referencing* the function as `fun countdown/1` returns the function itself as a value. That is, incidentally, why the function export declaration at the top of the module is written as `-module([countdown/1])`, because that is the explicit name of this function. Consider this:

```
1> c(example).
{ok,example}
2> example:countdown(2).
Counting down in: 2
Counting down in: 1
Blastoff!
ok
3> Countdown = fun example:countdown/1.
#Fun<example.countdown.1>
4> Countdown(2).
Counting down in: 2
Counting down in: 1
Blastoff!
ok
```

While I'm on the subject...

Erlang has very few keywords compared to most languages (and very little syntax, actually). Here is [the list of reserved words](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/introduction.html#id65034):

> after and andalso band begin bnot bor bsl bsr bxor case catch cond div end fun if let not of or orelse receive rem try when xor

Answer (score 1):

You just need to go back up:

```
f({1, 3}) -> {A, B} = {5, 2}, {B, A+1} -> {2, 6}
f({2, 2}) -> {A, B} = {2, 6}, {B, A+1} -> {6, 3}
```

(note that `fun` is a keyword in Erlang and that `f(N,M)` is not the same as `f({N,M})`)

> and do they change in each recursive call

Yes, as you can see.